# If I type "hello" into a text box, how can I make an alert appear by pressing a button?

Tags: javascript, css, html, button, input

I would like to create code to make it so when I type "hello" into a text box I can press the button below and a certain alert pop-up will appear. I also want to add more of these to different words as well. What should I add to my code to make this work?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>thisThat</title>
<style>
    body {
        background-color: #333333;
    }
    .input, .output {
       border: 0;
    padding: 8px;
    font-size: 14px;
    }
    .output {
        background-color: #ff0000;
    }
    p {
        font-size: 18px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<center><h3>thisThat</h3></center>
<center><p>
If
</p></center>
<center><input placeholder="this..." class="input"></center>
<center><p>then</p></center>
<center><button class="output">that...</button></center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Side note, don't use the `<center>` tag, it was deprecated circa 1950.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/wiki/Web_Standards_Curriculum#JavaScript_core_skills

Comment: What have you tried?  You need to at least attempt to solve your problem before asking how it's done.  Without actually learning how to do it you won't build on the fundamental basics that are essential to mastering the craft of coding.

Comment: I did try a few times but I deleted those. It was a solution from stackoverflow but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you do that with JavaScript.  There are some great online resources for learning HTML, CSS and JavaScript:  https://www.codeschool.com/ http://pluralsight.com/ http://teamtreehouse.com/